# dartaotruntime: command not found

Tags: linux, dart, ubuntu

I use Linux (i.e. Ubuntu 23.04)  and I installed the Dart SDK with the instructions mentioned on [Dart's website](https://dart.dev/get-dart). The dart command is accessible but I can not use the dartaotruntime command. The terminal says that the command is not found. What is the workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are an ongoing issue about the command are not on the PATH when installing the deb package for Dart: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49293

You can manually find the executable as `/usr/lib/dart/bin/dartaotruntime`. If you need it, I wound either recommend:

- Having `/usr/lib/dart/bin/` on your PATH.
- Add an alias in your shell.
- Or, manully put a symlink to this executable somewhere which are on your PATH.

Or you can just directly call it with the full PATH when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The command dartaotruntime is no longer included in the latest Dart SDK. Instead, you can use the dart command to run your Dart code. So, to run your Dart code, use the following command:

```
dart your_dart_file_name.dart
```

This command will run your Dart code without any issues. If you encounter any problems or have further questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: The command are still included in Dart SDK (at least official deb package from the Dart project) and is used when you have compiled your application into a AOT-snapshot without bundling the dartaotruntime inside your binary: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile#aot-snapshot . As described in my answer, the command are just missing from the PATH for some reasons in the official deb package. In Arch Linux, the command are part of the PATH by default.